# does "\copy" command handle commit and rollback in postgres?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I am trying execute .sql file with `psql`. I run .sql file inside i have written following query `\copy table name from .dumb`. So if the command fails, will it handle commit/rollback by default. or we need to take care of that.

Comment: please edit your Q. are you trying to run sql file or `\copy table from file`?..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `\copy` fails transaction will be aborted, here is example:

```
t=# \! cat s07
create table trans(i int);
copy s07 from '/no such file';
t=# begin;
BEGIN
t=# \i s07
CREATE TABLE
psql:s07:2: ERROR:  could not open file "/no such file" for reading: No such file or directory
t=# select * from trans;
ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
t=# end;
ROLLBACK
```

Comment: So whats behavior for commit.

Comment: i thought to use  conn.BeginTransaction(),,, in finally() block committing the changes to DB.

Comment: or can i add "commit;" after "\copy TableName From D:.dump" in my .sql File?

Answer (score 1):

All depends on version of PG you are running. Because default for psql is autocommit on. And in newer versions you cannot set it off. So every successful manually issued COPY or \copy command is immediately commited.