# Should I rollback a transaction with only COPY inside?

Tags: postgresql, go

I use postgres COPY in my Go backend. Copy is the only operation inside transaction. Should I roll it back if it failed?

```
func (pc *Postgres) Copy(records [][]interface{}) error {
    tx, err := pc.db.Begin()
    if err != nil {
        return errors.Wrap(err, "can't open transaction")
    }
    stmt, err := tx.Prepare(pq.CopyIn(pc.table, pc.columns...))
    if err != nil {
        return errors.Wrap(err, "can't prepare stmt")
    }
    for _, record := range records {
        if _, err := stmt.Exec(record...); err != nil {
            return errors.Wrap(err, "error exec record")
        }

    }

    if _, err = stmt.Exec(); err != nil {
        return errors.Wrap(err, "error exec stmt")
    }
    if err = stmt.Close(); err != nil {
        return errors.Wrap(err, "error close stmt")
    }
    if err = tx.Commit(); err != nil {
        return errors.Wrap(err, "error commit transaction")
    }
    return nil
}
```

As far as I understand if `\copy` fails transaction will be aborted([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41238424/does-copy-command-handle-commit-and-rollback-in-postgres)) and [rolled back](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/184032/postgresql-how-does-copy-from-behave-inside-a-transaction).

However in officials `lib/pq` [examples](https://github.com/lib/pq/blob/master/copy_test.go#L57) I see they always use rollback(but they have more than one operation).

Could somebody please guide me through these nuances?

Comment: in your code, the transacton is left idling if you encounter an error. Having a defered rollback ensure it is released when the function is left. The library is smart enough to not rollback if you had commited before. https://github.com/lib/pq/blob/master/conn.go#L579

Comment: thanks, it answers my question. If you post it as a separate answer it will mark as a correct.

Comment: thanks, but i figured out that this is a duplicate. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46421602/why-defer-a-rollback

Comment: not exactly, my initial though was do I need rollback at all

Answer (score 0):

It looks like part of the confusion is because [`\COPY`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/app-psql.html#APP-PSQL-META-COMMANDS-COPY) is not the same thing as [`COPY`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/sql-copy.html).

[`\COPY`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/app-psql.html#APP-PSQL-META-COMMANDS-COPY) (as referenced in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41238424/does-copy-command-handle-commit-and-rollback-in-postgres)) is a command in [psql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/app-psql.html) that "Performs a frontend (client) copy". In simple terms you run `psql` (a terminal-based front-end to PostgreSQL) on a computer and can `\COPY` data between the database and a file stored locally (or accessible from your machine). This command is part of `psql` and not something you can use via `lib/pq`.

[`COPY`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/sql-copy.html) is a Postgres SQL command that runs on the server; the file you are copying "must be accessible by PostgreSQL user (the user ID the server runs as) and the name must be specified from the viewpoint of the server". This is what you are calling in your application (from the [pq docs](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/lib/pq#hdr-Bulk_imports) "CopyIn uses COPY FROM internally" implementation [here](https://github.com/lib/pq/blob/master/copy.go#L21) and [here](https://github.com/lib/pq/blob/master/conn.go#L817))

So, as the [answer referenced](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46421989/11810946) by @mh-cbon states:

> the deferred rollback is there to ensure that the transaction is rolled back in case of an early return.

Consider:

```
tx, err := pc.db.Begin()
if err != nil {
    return errors.Wrap(err, "can't open transaction")
}
stmt, err := tx.Prepare(pq.CopyIn(pc.table, pc.columns...))
if err != nil {
    return errors.Wrap(err, "can't prepare stmt")
}
```

If the `Prepare` fails you have created a transaction and then return without closing it; this leaves the transaction open which is [not a good thing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33815267/what-are-the-consequences-of-not-ending-a-database-transaction). Adding a `defer tx.Rollback()` ensures that does not happen.

Comment: thanks, agree @mh-cbon answer is what i was looking for. so i shouldn't leave transaction open i any case

Comment: That is correct; when you begin a transaction a connection will be dedicated to that transaction so it's important that you either commit or rollback so the connection can be freed.